# NSMenu delegate not called to populate it

Tags: cocoa, nsmenu

I have a controller object that owns an NSMenu and is that menu's delegate, in the interest of lazy population.

However, neither `numberOfItemsInMenu:` nor `menuNeedsUpdate:` is ever called, and so the menu remains empty.

I have confirmed that:

- The controller object has not been deallocated. (The controller, in turn, owns the menu.)
- It does have a menu.
- The menu does have a delegate, and that is the controller.

If I implement `menuWillOpen:`, that *is* called, but [you're not supposed to populate the menu there](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSMenuDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSMenuDelegate/menuWillOpen:).

I tried sending the menu an `update` message, and that had no effect. The delegate remained un-called, and the menu remained empty.

In case it's relevant: This menu is not in the main menu; it is used elsewhere.

Why isn't the menu asking its delegate to populate it? Is there something I've missed, or is this just broken?

Comment: Can you paste your code here. So that we will also try it out?

Comment: @hussainShabbir: Nope. The code doesn't belong to me; I was working on a contract job. (Besides which, I already changed it to not rely on those methods being called by the system.)

Comment: I am having exactly same issue now, and your mention about `menuWillOpen:` saved my time a lot. For the record, `menuDidClose:` also makes same issue even for setting `enabled` property of a menu item. The only thing that working is `menuNeedsUpdate:`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need a strong reference to the delegate. 
 Try moving variable declaration out of your method and make a class-level member variable. 
look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21816149/1664943

Comment: You missed this part of the question: “I have confirmed that: • The controller object has not been deallocated.”

Comment: Did you have at one point a View setMenu:.. ? If yes- where do you have the Menu variable decelerated? In my case the controller also was NOT deallocated, but ARC has invalidated the reference to my delegate.

Comment: The controller object I was referring to is the menu's delegate and its owner.